# Mailgun refuses some emails on server

Tags: php, mailgun

I am having an absolute nightmare trying to diagnose an issue with Mailgun (or possibly the server).

Basically some emails never send, but some go through OK. I can see via Mailgun's logs that some emails are sending regularly (order notifications, contact form submissions, etc), but certain emails (particularly password reset) emails never get sent.

There is nothing in the Apache or PHP logs, there is nothing in Mailgun's logs (that I can see). Even more weird, when I try to send from my local development install, the email sends OK.

I have spent all afternoon trying to trace the execution process, I can see that this line executes fine: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/blob/v2.3.0/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php#L107

The resulting request look like this (had to json encode it to log it):

```
"\u0000GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request\u0000method":"POST",
"\u0000GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request\u0000requestTarget":null,
"\u0000GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request\u0000uri":{},
"\u0000GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request\u0000headers":
    {
    "Host":["api.mailgun.net"],
    "User-Agent":["mailgun-sdk-php\/1.7"],
    "Authorization":["Basic *****"],
    "Content-Type":["multipart\/form-data; boundary=\"5aff012a5f8bc7.02308610\""]
    },
    "\u0000GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request\u0000headerNames":{
        "user-agent":"User-Agent",
        "authorization":"Authorization",
        "content-type":"Content-Type",
        "host":"Host"
},
"\u0000GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request\u0000protocol":"1.1",
"\u0000GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request\u0000stream":{}
```

The execution seems to just exit here: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/blob/v2.3.0/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php#L108

I tried to trace it further, but starting to feel like I am going down a rabbit hole!

Has anyone had a similar issue? Do you know a solution or at the least an easier way to debug the problem?

Comment: You've just posted your API key to a public forum, you'll want to delete/revoke it immediately.

Comment: Bugger, this is what happens when you spend this long trying to solve a problem! Cheers Alex, I will update that ASAP!

Comment: the API key is still viewable in this question's edit history. Also, it doesn't look like you posted the request here. Where is the payload?

Comment: If I recall, I may have stripped that out. To be honest, in the end I shut the Mailgun account down, I was having the same issue with multiple projects on different servers. I am now using Postmark and it works perfectly.